# Speeding up iterations

Tags: vba, excel

When I am iterating items with my forloop to add items down through excel. My program slows down a lot and almost crashes as I can see the iterations happen. Is there a way to make this all process at once?

```
Set rng = Range("A1:C2")

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell in row.Cells
    'Do Something
  Next cell
Next row
```

Comment: Short Answer: Load everything into an array and iterate through that instead then post the array back.  Longer answer depends on what you want to do.  There are short cuts depending on what is wanted.

Comment: Iterating cells one by one is quite possibly ***the*** single slowest thing you can do in VBA. `Dim rng As Variant` and then `rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C2").Value` to work off a 2D variant array; use a `For` loop to iterate the array, it's going to be night and day.

Comment: Note that you can post your *actual, real, working code* on [codereview.se] to get constructive feedback on enhancing maintainability, readability, performance, etc. - note that "`'Do Something`" code isn't acceptable for Code Review though.

Comment: All of these guys have pretty solid advice^^^ Working with arrays is just something youll have to get used to. My suggestion is learning how to dump ranges into arrays, transpose 1d range into an array, redim arrays an transposing arrays. sounds like a lot but it isnt really. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on and off screen updating/events using:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Comment: That will only possibly help depending on what `'Do Something` is actually doing. The real bottleneck isn't screen updating or worksheet/workbook events, it's the fact that OP is *iterating individual cells*.